Fixed spacing/padding for labels
I'm a Vega Lite newbie and using Vega Lite using Deneb in PowerBI. I've created a bar chart showing the responses to a survey - the labels are the questions themselves so are quite long (up to 150 characters). There is a filter in PowerBI that determines the questions shown - the maximum length of the question/labels varies and so the actual plot area expands/contracts to fill the space available. If possible I'd like to keep the plot area the same - I've tried adding padding spacing to the questions to make them all the same length but Vega Lite is clever and removes/trims excess spaces! I've experimented with "Customizing Size" but with no success.
Is there a way to explicitly define the plot area position? e.g. "width": 300, "x": 200 where x is the absolute position of the start of the plot? Or alternatively to set a fixed width to the axis label area?
Please below example images - in these the size and position of the plot area changes depending on the selected set of questions - I'd like the plot position and size to remain constant if possible. This is an example code [Example PowerBI File] (https://sendanywhe.re/AGKNXTQ7)
Set A
Set B
Many thanks in advance for any help!

Does adding a minExtent do what you want?
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "width":400,  
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Question",
      "type": "nominal",
        "axis": {
        "labelAlign": "right",
        "labelLimit": 900,
        "labelFontSize": 10, "minExtent":350
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Sum of Good",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}


Hi davidebacci, Perfect! Works a treat - much appreciated.
